# How can i pass URL parameter to react js widget

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I have a react widget fetching data from an API (ex : `https://api.prime.com/v1/business/rating/${id}`)

In this example a list of informations with the `${id}` is rendered.

What I would like to do now is to get the ID via the scripts's url parameter :

`<script src="https://fr.prime.com/rating-widget/merchantidentifier"></script>`

for example in the code below `7182` is the `merchantidentifier`.

The `merchantidentifier` is variable, in this example `7182` goes in the `reactDOM.render()`

To show the widget on the merchant websites we need to add the script tag, in this example `<script src="https://fr.prime.com/rating-widget/7182"></script>`

How can I pass the `merchantidentifier` from the URL to the react app

```
var React = require('react');
import axios from 'axios';
import '../node_modules/cleanslate/cleanslate.css';
import './style.scss';

class Widget extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let id = this.props.id;
        axios.get(`https://api.prime.com/v1/business/rating/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
            const brand = res.data;
            this.setState({
                rating: brand.rating,
                logo : brand.logo,
                name: brand.name,
                stars: brand.stars,
                url: brand.url
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="cleanslate">
                <a href={this.state.url} target="_blank">
                    <img src="https://fr.prime.com/img.svg" alt="" />
                    <div className="rating-box">
                        <img src={this.state.logo} className="the-logo" alt={this.state.name} />
                        <span className="the-note">{this.state.rating}/10</span>
                        <div id="Star" className={`stars-${this.state.stars}`}></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(     
  <Widget id="7182" />,
  document.getElementById('root')        
);
```

Comment: Are you using react router?

Comment: No, it’s only a widget, if you add the script tag with merchant ID to the merchant website you will have rating infos of the merchant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not using [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/example-nested-routing) the only what I can think of

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
        this.id = '0';
        var urlComponents = window.location.href.split('/');
        if(urlComponents[urlComponents.length-2] === 'rating-widget') {
          this.id = urlComponents[urlComponents.length-1];
        }
    }
```

And in componentDidMount use like this

```
componentDidMount() {
   let id = process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER;
   axios.get(`https://api.prime.com/v1/business/rating/${this.id}`)
   ...
}
```

Comment: What about ReactDOM.render(<Widget id="7182" />,document.getElementById('root'));

Comment: Still you need to get the id from url right? If you are passing id via props, you need to check that first else take it from url

Comment: Yes i need to get the id from the URL, but i need to put something here <Widget id="?" />

Answer (score 2):

As your `script` tag is static and though the `merchantidentifier` is, which is not going to change at runtime.

You can make use of [`.env`](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables) file to store `merchantidentifier` and use whenever you want without explicitly passing.

Create `.env` file at root folder of your project,

```
REACT_APP_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER = 7182
```

Now you can use this in `HTML` as well as `JS` file.

You can use in `HTML` file as,

```
<script src="https://fr.prime.com/rating-widget/%REACT_APP_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER%"></script >
```

In `JS` file,

```
componentDidMount() {
   let id = process.env.REACT_APP_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER;
   axios.get(`https://api.prime.com/v1/business/rating/${id}`)
   ...
}
```

Comment: the merchantidentifier is not static, that’s the problem, we have a lot of merchants and everyone has an ID, 7182 is only an example

Comment: Thanks for this, I didnt know env vars were accessible with %REACT_APP_MERCHANT_IDENTIFIER%